# How to get key from json in angular

Tags: javascript, json, angular, angularjs

How to get key "employee "

{
employee":{"name":"John","age":12}

}

Comment: that appears to be invalid either as a string JSON object or as a JavaScript object since "employee" has no start quote

Comment: you can iterate over the keys of any object using `Object.keys(your-object)`, see e.g. [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: There is nothing specific to Angular here. You're going to need to know basic JS to be at all productive.

Answer (score 2):

It's not about Angular, this is plain Javascript:

```
const obj = { employee:{name:"John",age:12}}

const key = Object.keys(obj)[0]
```

Comment: i have json like this {"ex1":{"name":"John1","age":12}}, {"ex2":{"name":"John2","age":12}}, {"ex3":{"name":"John3","age":12}} ,i need add ex4 to this json.How it wil possible in js?

Comment: Assuming you have an array of objects and you want to include another one, you just need to push this new object to the array.

const items = [{"ex1":{"name":"John1","age":12}},
    {"ex2":{"name":"John2","age":12}},
    {"ex3":{"name":"John3","age":12}}]

items.push({"ex4":{"name":"John4","age":12}})

Answer (score 0):

You can use **forEach** to get your output if you use **Array Object**

```js
function example1(array){

    let res = [];
  array = [{"ex1":{"name":"John1","age":12}}, {"ex2":{"name":"John2","age":12}}, {"ex3":{"name":"John3","age":12}}]

    array.forEach((e, idx) => {
    res.push(Object.keys(e))
  })

  document.getElementById("ex1").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(res);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="example1" onclick="example1()">  

<p id="ex1"></p>
```

if you just use only **object** you can use **For...in** to get your output

```js
function example2(array){

    let res = [];
  obj = {"ex1":{"name":"John1","age":12}, "ex2":{"name":"John2","age":12}, "ex3":{"name":"John3","age":12}}

    for(var val in obj){
    res.push(val)
  }

  document.getElementById("ex2").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(res);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="example2" onclick="example2()">  

<p id="ex2"></p>
```

But remember when you put object or array or whatever check its valid or not. In your object is **invalid** here is the correct format

```
{"employee":{"name":"John","age":12}}
```